# When adding/removing last value from one listbox to another, whole listbox clears?

Tags: excel, vba, listbox, userform

I am creating a userform (`riskcodefiter`) where the user can move values over from one list box to another. The first list box `allriskcodes` contains many values (populated from a range on another worksheet), and the second list box `chosenriskcodes` will contain the values from `allriskcodes` the user wants to use as a filter. The userform includes `Btn_addallcodes`, `Btn_removeallcodes`, `Btn_addcodes`, `Btn_removecodes` - which are self explanatory.

The problem: If there are multiple values in the `chosenriskcodes` listbox, and the user wants to remove the last value in the box, it will clear the entire `chosenriskcodes` listbox. This is also the case for my `Btn_addcodes`. Any advice?

This is the code I have for my `Btn_removecodes`

```
Private Sub BTN_removecodes_Click()
     Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.chosenriskcodes.ListCount - 1
        If Me.chosenriskcodes.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
           Me.allriskcodes.AddItem Me.chosenriskcodes.List(iCtr)
        End If
    Next iCtr

    For iCtr = Me.chosenriskcodes.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Me.chosenriskcodes.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
           Me.chosenriskcodes.RemoveItem iCtr
        End If
    Next iCtr
End Sub
```

This is the code I have for my `Btn_addcodes`

```
    Private Sub BTN_addcodes_Click()
    Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.allriskcodes.ListCount - 1
        If Me.allriskcodes.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.chosenriskcodes.AddItem Me.allriskcodes.List(iCtr)
        End If
    Next iCtr

    For iCtr = Me.allriskcodes.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Me.allriskcodes.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.allriskcodes.RemoveItem iCtr
        End If
    Next iCtr

    End Sub
```

The button works fine for all the other values in the list boxes, except for the last value. Any ideas?

Comment: Your a counting from the previous to the last item here: `For iCtr = Me.chosenriskcodes.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1` you need to remove the -1 After `ListCount`

Comment: Hm, for some reason that doesn't fix the issue. It seems that this issue also occurs for my 'Btn_addcodes', when the last value is selected and "added" to `chosenriskcodes` listbox, it clears the entire `allriskcodes` listbox. I will add that to my original question as well.

Comment: Can't replicate this behaviour; you might have some covered interaction raised by your `xxriskcodes_Change` events and possibly select *all* listbox elements which of course would delete them. Suggestion: Instead of deleting elements you could populate a 2-dim array to rebuild the *remaining* values , e.g. via `temp(0,0)`, `temp(1,0)`.. `temp(n,0)` and assign it to the listboxe's `.List` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the issue happening if you insert breakpoints and watch what happens..

If there are say, 50 items in `allriskcodes` and the 50th item is selected, deleting it causes the 49th item to become selected (as if it's an active cursor).

The simple workaround is to deselect each item just before you delete it like so:

```
Private Sub BTN_addcodes_Click()
    Dim iCtr As Long

    For iCtr = 0 To Me.allriskcodes.ListCount - 1
        If Me.allriskcodes.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.chosenriskcodes.AddItem Me.allriskcodes.List(iCtr)
        End If
    Next iCtr

    For iCtr = Me.allriskcodes.ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
        If Me.allriskcodes.Selected(iCtr) = True Then
            Me.allriskcodes.Selected(iCtr) = False
            Me.allriskcodes.RemoveItem iCtr
        End If
    Next iCtr

End Sub
```

---

Also, to make this more readable, you could use the `With` statement:

```
Private Sub BTN_addcodes_Click()

    Dim iCtr As Long
    With Me.allriskcodes

        For iCtr = 0 To .ListCount - 1
            If .Selected(iCtr) = True Then
                Me.chosenriskcodes.AddItem .List(iCtr)
            End If
        Next iCtr

        For iCtr = .ListCount - 1 To 0 Step -1
            If .Selected(iCtr) = True Then
                .Selected(iCtr) = False
                .RemoveItem iCtr
            End If
        Next iCtr

    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Works beautifully! Thanks.